# How to Populate jQuery multiselect plugin with two sides with records from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I came across this plugin online. It enables me to add a selected text from one side and then add it to another side. I have intergrated it well in my project but i would love to display the text from my  table in my database.
Below is the definition of some of the text i have added to it but want this text to be populated from my database since they can change at anytime. The jquery plugin i'm using is pickList plugin. I do have an idea that i would need to make use of Ajax to achieve this but i still need a bit more explanation and guide

```
 var val = {
                 01: { id:01, text: 'HYGEIA HMO LIMITED ' },
                 02: { id:02, text: 'TOTAL HEALTH TRUST LIMITED' },
                 03: { id:03, text: 'CLEARLINE INTERNATIONAL LIMITED' },
};
 var pick = $("#pickList").pickList({ data: val });
```

Here is just a simple of sample code. If you have used this plugin before or something similar and has been able to populate the text from db, kindly give an insight. Thanks. I'm using asp.net anyway.

updated

```
public object GetHmo()
        {
            try
            {
                var Result = medical.Service_Rendereds.ToList();
               var ID= new List<int>();
                var Names = new List<string>();
                if (Result.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in Result)
                    {
                        ID.Add(item.Id);
                        Names.Add(item.HospitalServices);
                    }
                }
                return new 
                {
                    id = ID,
                    names = Names
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new
                {

                };
            }
        }





$(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "../HealthCareServices.asmx/GetHmo",
                     data: '{}',
                     dataType: "json",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     async: true,
                     cache: false,
                     success: function (response) {

                     }
                 });
             });
             function renderResult(response)
             {
}
```

Comment: you just need to make an ajax call which returns the contents of `val` (or the equivalent data which the server generates) as a JSON object. There are lots of tutorials online about a) how to make an ajax call and return JSON and b) how to make a JSON webservice / webmethod using the various flavours of ASP.NET. Have you looked up or tried any? Give it a try and then update your question with what you tried, if you get stuck.

Comment: i just created a webservice method to get my data. Where i am currently stocked is how to pass the id and text(name) returned into var Val

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as per the comments, that you have a webservice which returns a list of JSON objects in the format you've shown, you can make an ajax call similar to 
this to populate the picklist:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: "../HealthCareServices.asmx/GetHmo",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response)
    {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); //just for debugging, see the structure of the returned data
        //assign the JSON data in the response to the picklist
        var pick = $("#pickList").pickList({ data: response });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //handle any HTTP errors which occur
        console.log("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jqXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR.responseJSON));
    }
});
```

Note I've used a "GET" instead of a post. To get data from the server, the convention is to used GET (the clue's in the name!). POST is usually for sending data.

This is the theory. However, I'm not convinced your webservice will return the data in the format you require. You should test it with a tool like Postman or SOAPUI to check that the data format matches what you need. I've also added a debugging line in the "success" callback so you can see the returned data structure in your console.

Comment: @Mcbaloo did the answer help you in any way? If so please remember to upvote and/or mark as accepted answer - thanks :-)